# Assign scores to sentences for their 'quality'

Tags: python, nlp, sentence

I have scrapped a lot of pages from a specific domain and I would like to identify which sentences from the  text of these pages are more useful in terms of information they carry. Is there an NLP technique to do it? An example would be:

```
sent0 = "The cat is white"
sent1 = "Cat"
sent2 = "The reason why the cat is white is due to a certain type of pigmentation its fur contains"
```

Where the scores would be decrescent in the order: sent2, sent0, sent1.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is there an example where a shorter sentence should score higher than a longer one?

Comment: "A cat woke red fell killed where done fine alright bad cat cat cat" should have a very low score

Answer (score 2):

I guess one thing that you can try is Information Retrieval Score. You could use traditional information retrieval methods like TF-IDF (Term Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency) to score the sentences. Sentences with higher scores are considered to be more important.

However, it seems to me TF-IDF doesn't handle semantics well, it's more about how often certain terms appear.

Comment: I have thought about it and it probably is a useful metric to use, but my data comes from scrapping pages and quite often I have short sentences that don't repeat tokens while don't make much sense either (what would yield a high score).

I think I need something that takes semantics into account, if it exists.

Comment: @Lucas Azevedo I see, thanks for the information! Maybe it would be helpful to use Transformer-based models, such as BERT, GPT, or RoBERTa. I am not so familiar with these models, hope there will be other answers related to them!